# Get rid of auto spacing using bquote in r

Tags: r, axis, label, spaces

I am attempting to label a plot axis in r using the bquote function. The desired string includes the greek mu character and a variable.

This results in spaces in either side of the mu:

```
xlab = bquote("Lake NO3 (" ~ mu ~ "mol/L): " ~ .(i))
```

How can I get rid of the spaces next to mu?

I tried using paste and paste0 expressions, but neither of these allow both a greek character and a variable.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

If you want to get rid off space on either side of `mu`

```
i <- 25
plot(1, xlab=bquote("Lake NO3 ("*mu*"mol/L): " ~.(i) ))
```

If you need space on the right

```
plot(1, xlab=bquote("Lake NO3 ("*mu~ "mol/L): " ~.(i) ))
```